# JPA: fetching bidirectional many to one relationship

Tags: java, jpa, orm, jpql, datanucleus

I'm a beginner to the JPA/JPQL stuff and I'm having problems fetching many-to-one relationships when I make the relationship bi-directional. Here is the JPQL:

```
select c from Child c join fetch c.parent
```

Here are the two simple classes:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id
    private int id;

    private String title;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private Set<Child> children;
}
@Entity
public class Child {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Parent parent;

}
```

The equivalent SQL query executed by datanucleus is:

```
SELECT 'com.*.Child' AS NUCLEUS_TYPE,`C`.`ID`,`C`.`PARENT_ID` FROM `CHILD` `C` INNER JOIN `PARENT` `B0` ON `C`.`PARENT_ID` = `B0`.`ID`
```

Now if I completely remove the reference to "children" in Parent, the SQL is exactly what I need:

```
SELECT 'com.*.Child' AS NUCLEUS_TYPE,`C`.`ID`,`B0`.`ID`,`B0`.`TITLE` FROM `CHILD` `C` INNER JOIN `PARENT` `B0` ON `C`.`PARENT_ID` = `B0`.`ID`
```

**To be clear:** what I'm trying to achieve is to fetch the child's parent with my JPQL query.

**Update:** I just tried these two classes with EclipseLink and this works, so looks like this problem is Datanucleus-specific.

Comment: If you just want the parent and you have the child, you can say
`FROM Parent p WHERE p.id = :parent_id`

Comment: I would like the child and the parent in one single query/transaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, this was a Datanucleus bug. It has been fixed in datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.6. This is the commit for the fix:

http://sourceforge.net/p/datanucleus/code/18118/

Answer (score 0):

1. You need `@JoinColumn` to create bidirectional relation:

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
   private Parent parent;
2. If you are using JPA annotations `select c from Child c` and than `child.getParent()` on objects from database should be enough.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to get the child and it's parent in one query, ie as a join. Your suggested solution in point 2 executes two separate queries.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use @JoinColumn in the Child class and try this.

Parent:

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = Child.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parent", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
```

Child:

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity=Parent.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="id", nullable = false)
```

And when you fetch the data from parent table it will automatically contains the associated data from the child table in the Set 'children'

Comment: This makes no difference

Comment: I don't why it doesn't make any change but I have tried in this way it worked for me.